# Restricting Approval workflow only for files within a folder or document-set in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, folder, document-set

I have a SharePoint online document library with multiple folders/Document-sets. 
I want to allow approval to files within only one folder/document-set of the document library.
The workflow should not be visible to files in other folders/document-sets of document library.

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB feature to restrict workflow on for one folder or document set in SharePoint. We can restrict workflow in site level, list/document library level or content type level.

As a workaround, I suggest you creating a custom content type and assign this content type to the files in the specific folder.

Then create a reusable workflow with the relevant content type in SharePoint Designer.

[image]